# Parse by pattern, Sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to parse mikrotik value, here's what I got :
But, when I check there is no hostname in IP 192.168.10.5

```
active-address=192.168.10.1
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="oXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.2 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="ZXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.3 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="OXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.4 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="AXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.5 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
active-address=192.168.10.6 <-- This is should be host-name
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="TXXXX"
```

I want to add string `host-name="-"` after mac-address of IP 192.168.10.5
The pattern always same like that..

```
active-address=192.168.10.1
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="oXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.2 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="ZXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.3 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="OXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.4 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="AXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.5 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="-" <--- I want to append
active-address=192.168.10.6
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="TXXXX"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic sed that will find all missing host names, with the assumption that all have active mac addresses.

```
sed '/active-mac-address/{N;/host-name/!s/\n/\nhost-name="-"\n/}' file
```

As pointed out by Ed, this will die on solaris, and will not match the final line of the file.

Comment: Yes!! Yes!! Thanks you!! Thank you!! Aaahh I really happy!!! Thanks for solve my problem!!

Comment: That will fail if the missing host name is from the last block in the file. That's not a generic sed, btw - use of `\n` is non-portable and some seds (e.g. on Solaris) would choke on some of the other constructs too: `sed: command garbled: /active-mac-address/{N;/host-name/!s/\n/\nhost-name="-"\n/}`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah i noticed that, but the command would become a bit unruly to match if it was at the end. Also I didn't know `/n` was not portable, do you know of any alternative ?

Comment: Yes the portable way to include a newline in a sed command is a backslash followed by a literal newline character.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah okay I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on single lines, that is all. All of the arcnae single-character sed constructs to do anything else became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Just use awk for clarity, simplicity, robustness, extensibility and most other desirable attributes of software:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^active-address/ { prtRec() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prtRec() }

function prtRec() {
    if (rec != "") {
        rec = rec (rec~/host-name/ ? "" : "host-name=\"-\"\n")
        printf "%s", rec
        rec = ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
active-address=192.168.10.1
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="oXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.2 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="ZXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.3 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="OXXXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.4 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="AXXX" 
active-address=192.168.10.5 
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="-"
active-address=192.168.10.6
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="TXXXX"
```

Note that the above will work whether or not the missing host-name is from the end of the file:

```
$ cat file2
active-address=192.168.10.6
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
$ 
$ awk -f tst.awk file2
active-address=192.168.10.6
active-mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
host-name="-"
```

Want the output in CSV or any other form? Just make a couple of tweaks to the function that prints the record, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst2.awk         
/^active-address/ { prtRec() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prtRec() }

function prtRec() {
    if (rec != "") {
        rec = rec (rec~/host-name/ ? "" : "host-name=\"-\"\n")
        sub(/^[^=]+=/,"",rec)      # tweak 1: remove leading "...="
        gsub(/\n[^=]+=/,",",rec)   # tweak 2: change every "\n...=" to ","
        printf "%s", rec
        rec = ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst2.awk file
192.168.10.1,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,"oXXXXX"
192.168.10.2,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,"ZXXXXX"
192.168.10.3,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,"OXXXXX"
192.168.10.4,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,"AXXX"
192.168.10.5,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,"-"
192.168.10.6,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,"TXXXX"
```